# Merging json files together in php

Tags: php, json

I'm iterating over a directory and merging the JSON-Files in it. But it doesn't quite work as i want it to. The array I get after iterating over 3 files is just the last file. Somewhere along the way it seems to just overwrite the previous files. I'm not sure where though. Also I would like to remove rows with certain entries, but I'd be happy if the merging would work at least.

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("path1");
$destination = "path2";
$json = file_get_contents($destination);
$result = json_decode($json,true); 
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $path = $dir -> getPathname();
        $data = file_get_contents($path);

        echo $data; //works as intended. Prints 3 different Arrays after eachother

        $current = json_decode(file_get_contents($path),true);
        $result = array_merge($result,$current);
    }
}
$final = json_encode($result);
file_put_contents($destination,$final);
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does each file content start with `[`, or with `{`?

Comment: @trincot it starts with     {

Comment: Then please realise that if two of these arrays share keys, the first key will be overwritten by the last. That is the effect of `array_merge`. In the extreme case, if both arrays have exactly the same keys (but with different values), you will be left over with the last array only. Can you check whether this is the case?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty certain they have the same keys since its the same table just to a different time and therefore different values but the same keys. Is there a way to prevent the override?

Comment: Well, then you need to tell me what result you expect? Because a key is unique in an associative array. What you could have, is a key that has as value a nested array listing the different values it has in each of the files. Is that what you want? Or do you want an array of arrays, where the content of each file is considered an element of a wrapping array?

Comment: The goal is to have one big JSON-file in which I have all the different iterations of the same table (it's like snapshots in time), so i can analyze over them in matlab. A nested array would probably work. array of arrays is probably better tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `array_merge` has this overwriting behaviour, as specified in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.

This effect can be illustrated with this little example:

```
$a1 = array("a" => 1, "b" => 2);
$a2 = array("a" => 100, "b" => 200);
$result = array_merge($a1, $a2);
print_r (json_encode($result));
```

output:

> {"a":100,"b":200}

So, the values of the first array are lost.

There are several solutions, but it depends on which result you would like to get. If for instance you would like to get this:

> {"a":[1, 100],"b":[2, 200]}

Then use the function [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead of `array_merge`.

If you prefer to get this:

> [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":100,"b":200}]

Then use this code:

```
$result[] = $a1;
$result[] = $a2;
```

In your original code, that last solution would look like this:

```
$result[] = json_decode($json,true); 
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    // ...
        $result[] = $current;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast help! Can I give u some kind of recommendation for being a great user or something? Pretty new to all of this

Comment: Once you have 5 points more reputation, you can upvote an answer (using the up arrow). So if you want, go get that reputation and come back :-)